# Move (not copy) files from Windows to Unix using unix command

Tags: shell-script, windows, ftp

I need to execute a datastage ETL job which runs a shell script to move files from a specific folder in windows machine (not a file system) to a directory in unix.

I have something like this now

```
HOST=UNIX123
USER=abcd
PASSWORD=abc123
FILE_NAME="Test.txt"
ftp -v -n WINDOWS123 << end_script
user zxc/VKR XYZ
lcd /stg/scripts 
cd "data" 
binary
mget *.txt
quit
end_script
```

The mget command here just copies the files. I would want to move the files instead of a copy

Comment: By, "to a folder in unix" you mean a folder on another partition?

Comment: Do you mean a remote Windows machine, or do you mean some Windows *file-system* (e.g. NTFS) mounted on Linux? Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot (currently it is unclear). BTW, Unix systems have *directories* (not folders, which are just a GUI artefact). And what is a "datastage" job?

Comment: you state two machines. 1 windows 1 linux. how they are related? is the nix machine running samba? is the windows running FTP/SFTP service? will the windows machine deliver to unix the files via FTP/SFTP? plz share more details on what exactly the relation will be between the servers?

Comment: And your question is... ?

Comment: Can we assume that the listed user has Windows permissions to delete the files?

Comment: Yes the user does. But I do not want to delete the file after copy because there might be scenarios where in a file comes after copy was made and if we delete it then, we will miss processing them.

Comment: Use an array of file names to copy then delete. That way if the file shows up in the middle of the process it will not be deleted.

Comment: I am not sure how to code that. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows box with at least an admin share `\\computer\c$` and you have a linux box that will run the script:

Mount the windows share read/write

```
mount -t cifs $network_path $mount_directory -o credentials=$cred_file
```

Execute the move command on the mounted directory

```
mv "$mount_directory/*" "$new_directory"
```

May need to copy then delete the files...

```
cp "$mount_directory/*"
rm "$mount_directory/*"
```

Check the switches you may require on the commands (`cp`, `mv` and `rm`).